# Transition on gradient button?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a transition for this button I have on this mockup navbar I'm making and when I hover over, I want a 0.5s transition for a background change, but it isn't working I haven't really used transitions much in css, but this is what the great google has told me :

```
.btn-primary {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0066FF 0, #0088FF 85%, #00AAFF 100% );
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0000CC 0, #0044CC 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lApnj

Any information would be great thanks! :)

Comment: It may "work" but its obviously not transitioning like the OP expects ..

Comment: @kellyjohnson It's supposed to kind of, fade / transition in, not just be an instant change of color

Comment: yes, that what it is doing for me in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any support for CSS3 gradient transition. ***YET***. However, you could try something like this:

Button

```
<a class="btn_primary" href="#">A button</a>
```

CSS

```
.btn_primary {
    background-color : #6BFF8A;
    background-image : linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 100%);
    color : #fff;
    display : block;
    font-family : arial,sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px;
    padding : 5px 10px;
    text-align : center;
    text-decoration : none;
    transition : background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
    width : 75px;
}
.btn_primary:hover {
    background-color : #900;
}
```

And here's a [little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BL9SJ/) I created for you.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lApnj Any idea why my button has that 'flash' to it on mouse over?

Comment: It's because you're transitioning the background-color, but it doesn't have an initial background-color set.

Comment: Updated the pen, check again it still flashes :/

Comment: @XCritics I created a new pen for you. Check it out, and let me know how it works for you. [codepen.io/anon/pen/fixtq](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fixtq)

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the transition in the normal state of your class like this:

```
.btn-primary {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0066FF 0, #0088FF 85%, #00AAFF 100% );
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0000CC 0, #0044CC 100%);
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

**EDIT**: this is actually **wrong** since, as ***Kacey*** said, there is no support for transition with gradients. Sorry for the mistake